# Finding the subset of a dictionary that has the minimum edit distance to a given string

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, string-matching, edit-distance

I'm looking for the most efficient way of solving an [Levenshtein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) problem.

We are given as input:

> 1. A set of strings `S` of size `n` <= 8, with average length `m` <= 50
> 2. A target string `t` of length `l` <= 50

Our task is to 'align' `t` with `S` i.e:

> Find the subset `s*` of `S`, where `concat(s*)` has the minimum Levenshtein edit distance (among all the subsets) with `t`

Some thoughts:

1. For 2 strings of length `l1` and `l2`, we could use the standard dynamic programming algorithm which has `O(l1*l2)` time complexity
2. Brute forcing this would require us to compute `editDistance(t, concat(s')) for each subset s'`. This would be approximately `O(l.m.n!)`
3. This could be optimized a bit by memoizing the results i.e if we are computing `editDistance(t, S[1, 2, 3, 4])` we could re-use the computation from `S[1, 2, 3]`)
4. The other option I could think of is to construct a [Trie or DAWG (Directed Acyclic Word Graph)](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/?id=114)

But, I'm not an expert on this, so I might be missing a better solution. How would we do this efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Optimization idea: length difference >=  Levenshtein - distance (could be a shortcut in some cases)

Comment: `concat(s*)` requires the elements of `s*` to be ordered in some way.  Is there a particular order (i.e., you really mean "sequence" and "subsequence" instead of "set" and "subset"), or is it required to find the best ordering?

Answer (score 0):

Outline of a memoize solution. (I just didn't do levenshtein for you.)

```
def best_answer(S, t, p0=0, p1=None, cache=None):
    # Defaults
    if cache is None:
        cache = {}
    if p1 is None:
        p1 = len(t)
    if ('s', p0, p1) not in cache:
        best_strings = []
        best_error = p1 - p0
        for s in S:
            leven = levenshtein(s, t[p0:p1])
            if leven < best_error:
                best_strings = [s]
                best_error = leven
        for p in range(p0+1, p1):
            (best_strings0, best_error0) = best_answer(S, t, p0, p, cache)
            (best_strings1, best_error1) = best_answer(S, t, p, p1, cache)
            if best_error0 + best_error1 < best_error:
                best_strings = best_strings0 + best_strings1
                best_error = best_error0 + best_error1
        cache[(p0, p1)] = (best_strings, best_error)
    return cache[('s', p0, p1)]
```